# Allow incoming SCP connections on Mac

Tags: macos, scp

How can I allow incoming `scp` connections on my Mac (OS X 10.6.4) from other machines on the same network?

Every time I’m trying to `scp` something on the machine I get a **Connection refused** error.

**Later edit:**

The command used is this:

```
scp path/to/local.file user@remote.machine:
```

And the reply is this:

```
ssh: connect to remothe.machine port 22: Connection refused
lost connection
```

Comment: can you post the format of the statement you are using to make this connection?

Comment: @MaQleod: see my edit

Comment: It sounds as if you need to enable SSH/SCP.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

*System Preferences* pane → *Sharing* applet → check the **Remote Login** checkbox. This will enable SSH, and in turn, SCP.

Answer (score 5):

In the settings there is the option to activate SSH. I think it’s under *Sharing* → *Remote Login*.

Answer (score 2):

You might have to open a port. My router's address is 192.168.0.1, it's default name is admin and password is, I think, password. Yours might be the same. Check the bottom of your router. Default port is 22.

Comment: While a closed port on a firewall will cause connection issues, it will cause a time out and not a refused connection. A refused connection is a specific error caused by the TCP handshake being shutdown due to no listening service. In other words, an RST is sent in response to the client's SYN.

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Sharing -> Check Remote Access -> Right panel, allow full disk access

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV8bK.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).